# How to combine a webhook and a push notification?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, webhooks, discord

There is a website, where push notifications come up when certain actions happen. I want to bind a webhook from Discord app to these push notifications, so that when a push notification comes up, a message in my Discord channel is sent.

I don't know what programming languages are involved or what to do even. Please guide me on what sort of technology is used. Googling and similar search only led me to self-promotion posts of third party services. So far I've found that webhooks use API and things are usually implemented via third party services, but I want to actually code this from scratch.